# Permission-Based Class Based Views Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How do I make it such that you can only view the members list if you are part of the member list.
I don't even know what the "permission required" in my MemberListView as this part was done by my expert friend, so I commented it out. (Hope someone can share what that is as well, super new to writing class based views)

Basically for my current code, I tried to make it such that if the user that is currently logged in don't belong in the list, they will be redirected away.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 members    = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="members")
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
class MemberListView(LoginRequiredMixin,BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = 'must_authenticate'    
    template_name = "HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html"
    #permission_required = ('blogpost.view_all_blogpost_members')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user in object.members.all:
            return render('HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html', context)
        else:
            return render('HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context)
```

template:

```
<ul>
    {% for member in object.members.all %}
    <li>{{member.username}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Based on Niespodd answer:

```
class MemberListView(LoginRequiredMixin,BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user in self.get_object().members.all:
            return redirect('HomeFeed:member_list')
```

Based on JPG answer:

```
class MemberListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = 'must_authenticate'    
    template_name = "HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user in object.members.all:
            return render('HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html', context)
        else:
            return render('HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user in post.members.objects.all()
```

Comment: [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin)

Comment: both are not the same

Comment: How do you creating the `BlogPost`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather use the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) class to handle the ***permissions*** as

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin


class MemberListView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UserPassesTestMixin,
    BlogPostMixin,
    DetailView
):
    login_url = 'must_authenticate'
    template_name = "HomeFeed/membersof_yourpost.html"

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user in post.members.all()
```

**Note:** You don't need to override the [**`get_context_data()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method in this case and most importantly, the `get_context_data()` method supposed to return a ***dict*** like object

Comment: Hi JPG, not sure if this is what you mean? i have included what you adviced me to do into the question and got an error: Attribute Error: `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: based on what I have read, the test func simply makes sure that the user is in the member list correct? then the get context data will help to do the redirect?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be `post.members.all()` (updated the answer)

Comment: No, the execution will not read to the `get_context_data()` method unless the `test_func(...)` method returns `True`

Comment: bro, now it says 403 forbidden...so i guess it works? is there a way to make it such that the author of the blog post will always automatically be in the member list?

Comment: so basically I can just remove the `get_context_data` function?

Comment: Thats what I mentioned in the ***Note*** section. For the ***new question/query*** ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824038/how-can-i-automatically-add-the-blogpost-author-into-the-member-list

Answer (score 2):

The `permission_required` refers to `PermissionRequiredMixin` that most likely `BlogPostMixin` inherits from. Its documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin

With the default implementation of `PermissionRequiredMixin` user will get an access denied error page.

The easiest solution if you are new to class-based views would be to simply override the `dispatch` method on `MemberListView` and check for user's membership there.

Something along the lines of:

```py
class MemberListView( ... ):
    def dispatch( ... ):
        if self.request.user in self.get_object().members.all:
            return redirect( ... )
```

Comment: What should be in the parameter of the dispatch function though?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L90

Comment: cause i received this error: `argument of type 'method' is not iterable` @niespodd

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.save()
obj.members.add(request.user) #change is here
```